# How to Disable radio button in runtime visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-c++

In Runtime i want to give radio button option 
"Disable" = True, 
initially i set "Disable" = False.

Answer (score 3):

WinAPI:

```
HWND hCtl = GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDC_RADIO);
EnableWindow(hCtl, FALSE);
```

MFC:

```
GetDlgItem(IDC_RADIO)->EnableWindow(FALSE);
```

Comment: Do you consider it safe to directly use the result of `GetDlgItem` without testing?

Comment: Of course not. This is a simplified example with no error checking/handling at all.